# Nonperiodic space-filling polyhedra

Tags: 3d, polyhedra, solid-geometry, tiling

For periodic space-filling polyhedra, the maximum number of faces seems to be 38, according to [On Space Groups and Dirichlet-Voronoi Stereohedra](https://refubium.fu-berlin.de/handle/fub188/10176).

For non-periodic space-filling polyhedra, the [Schmitt–Conway–Danzer biprism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyrobifastigium) is known.  Are there any others?

Comment: I guess you want them convex, otherwise anything is possible.

Comment: Yes, convex.  I'd be shocked if there's only one.